# Why name hiding occurs instead of redefinition in some cases?

Tags: c++, declaration

In C++ there is the One Definition Rule that states that(C++ ISO draft 2020, 6.3, first paragraph):

> No translation unit shall contain more than one definition of any
> variable, function, class type, enumeration type, template, default
> argument for a parameter (for a function in a given scope), or default
> template argument.

What made me think about the following codes

```
//Code 1
int main(){
  int a=1;
  int a=2;
}
//Code 2
int main(){
  int a=1;
  {
    int a=2;
  }
}
```

Code 1 generates a error because of a redefinition, which isn't allowed. But why the second works fine? I know that the inner declaration hides the outer one, but why this happens and there is no redefinition problem? Analogous why in the first code there is no hiding, but a redefinition error?

Comment: Variables at different scopes are different, even if they have the same name. In code 1, they're at the same scope so it's a redefinition.

Comment: Your compiler may warn you about `a` hiding an outer scope variable

Comment: @NathanPierson, by the way, you know where I could find about this in the ISO?

Comment: @Roman - It's in all C++ standards.   In C++98 (ISO/IEC 14882) Section 3.3 "Declarative regions and scopes" discusses this (and para 2 in that section has a relevant example).    The same section (possibly with minor wording updates) is in C++17 as Section 6.3.1.   I don't have a copy of C++ standards after 2017 handy on my current PC, but would expect the same (or similar) section in later standards (possibly with different section numbering).

Answer (score 1):

The most basic reason is that the first program **can’t** use both variables `a` while the second can (albeit never on the same line).  The more nuanced reason is that it’s (usually) a feature that (more) local names do not have to be chosen so as to **avoid** all (more) global names, as whenever `log` is used to refer to logging rather than the `<cmath>` function `::log`.

At a more technical level, the two declarations in the same scope are taken to be declarations of the **same** variable ([basic.link]/8 in the current draft), just as two declarations

int f();

in the global scope are taken to refer to the same function.  Obviously the same variable cannot be initialized twice; in general, the position of the definition matters.